# Understanding decorators: return type is a function when argument not specified

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am using a single decorator for two separate functions: one with specification of a decorator argument; and another one without it.

When the optional argument is not passed, the return type is a function (specifically, the `inner_function` in the decorator). However, when the optional argument is passed it works as expected.

Can you explain what is going on here and why it acts differently in these cases?

```
def cache_disk(cache_folder="./cache"):
    def wrapper(f):
        def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return inner_function
    return wrapper

@cache_disk
def func1(data):
    return [d for d in data]

@cache_disk(cache_folder='./cache/')
def func2(data):
    return [d for d in data]


data = [1,2,3]
print(func1(data))
print(func2(data))
```

Result:

```
<function inner_function at 0x7f1f283d5c08>
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that:

```
@decorator  # no arguments
def func(...):
    ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
def func(...):
    ...

func = decorator(func)  # one 'level' of calls
```

and that:

```
@decorator(...):  # arguments
def func(...):
    ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
def func(...):
    ...

func = decorator(...)(func)  # two 'levels' of calls
```

In the first case, there is a single argument to the decorator, the `func` itself. In the second case, the arguments to the decorator are the `...` from the `@` line, and it's *the function returned by the decorator* that is called with `func` as an argument.

---

In your example,

```
@cache_disk
def func1(data):
    ...
```

the decorator `cache_disk` gets a single, callable argument (`func`, which becomes `args[0]`) and returns the `wrapper`. Then when you call:

```
print(func1(data))
```

`wrapper` gets a single argument (`data`, which becomes `f`) and returns `inner_function`.

Therefore, you have three choices:

1. Decorate `func1` with `@cache_disk()` (note parentheses), passing no arguments to `cache_disk` itself and `func` to `wrapper`;
2. Alter `cache_disk` to behave differently depending on whether it's passed a single, callable argument or something else; or
3. As [@o11c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405588/o11c) pointed out in the comments, use e.g. `cache_disk.wrapper = cache_disk()` to provide a convenient alias for the parameter-less version, then decorate with `@cache_disk.wrapper`.

Comment: It's worth noting that some decorator libraries use `@x` vs `@x.y` to separate cases.

Comment: @o11c in this case would that be like allowing `@cache_disk.wrapper`? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: Yeah, it's that simple. `cache_disk.wrapper = cache_disk()` even.

Comment: Though now that I think more about it, what is the most common form? That should be the outer one. So probably backwards, which requires more work to set up the assignments.

Answer (score 1):

if you want default values, you need to call the function, which returns a decorator:

```
@cache_disk()
def func1(data):
    return [d for d in data]
```